# Basic assembly code crashes DOS emulator

Tags: assembly

I am a very new assembly coder and most of it is still foreign to me. My code is as follows

```
0100: mov ah, 09
0102: mov dx, 010A
0105: int 21h
0107: int 20h
010A: db "Hello World!$"
```

Running this code in my DOS emulator (DosBox) causes the emulator window to produce the "Hello World !" message and continue to freeze and eventually give the "program is not responding" error.

Comment: Works fine in my dosbox. Maybe try `mov ax, 4C00h; int 21h` instead of `int 20h` to exit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It freezes because you didn't properly quit your application. Try that instead:

```
mov ah, 4C00h; 
int 21;
```

which should do the trick.
As to explanation of what is going on here, we have to grab a reference for [INT 20](http://stanislavs.org/helppc/int_20.html) and [INT 21](http://stanislavs.org/helppc/int_21-4c.html). As you can see they are both intended to terminate the application, but INT 20 is the legacy way to do it and was later replaced with 21,4c. The main difference between the two is that INT 20 just terminates the process, while INT 21,4C also returns appropriate return code (which is expected by all modern applications).

As of the construct itself, by moving "4C00h" (you should be able to get away with just "4Ch") to registry AH , we tell INT 21 which function we are interested in. Because unlike INT 20, which has only one purpose, [INT 21 has a long list of them](http://stanislavs.org/helppc/int_21.html), and by setting appropriate values in registries, INT 21 knows what is expected of it.

Comment: Thanks Puciek, that worked perfectly! Could you explain the difference between int 20h (which I was told terminates your program) and mov ah, 4C00?

Comment: @user2581242 I've expanded the answer.

Comment: @user2581242: Additionally to Puciek's answer take a look at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/72848/en-us. For `INT 20h` it is important that CS points to a **correct** PSP which is e.g not guaranteed by `DEBUG.EXE`.